# How do I call a function inside of another function?

Tags: javascript, function

I just want to know how to call a javascript function inside another function.
If I have the code below, how do I call the second function inside the first?

```
function function_one()
{
alert("The function called 'function_one' has been called.")
//Here I would like to call function_two.
}

function function_two()
{
alert("The function called 'function_two' has been called.")
}
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

```js
function function_one() {
    function_two(); // considering the next alert, I figured you wanted to call function_two first
    alert("The function called 'function_one' has been called.");
}

function function_two() {
    alert("The function called 'function_two' has been called.");
}

function_one();
```

A little bit more context: this works in JavaScript because of a language feature called "variable hoisting" - basically, think of it like *variable/function declarations are put at the top of the scope* ([more info](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript)).

Comment: what if `function_one` is a callable function. 
Such as in case of following mutation example. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

How can one call the function_two from within the callable function.

Comment: @SizzlingCode I'm not sure how that is any different than my code above. The reason this code works is because of "variable hoisting": https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript

Answer (score 23):

```
function function_one() {
  function_two(); 
}

function function_two() {
//enter code here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
function function_one()
{
    alert("The function called 'function_one' has been called.")
    //Here u would like to call function_two.
    function_two(); 
}

function function_two()
{
    alert("The function called 'function_two' has been called.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function function_first() {
    function_last(); 
    alert("The function called 'function_first' has been called.");
}

function function_last() {
    alert("The function called 'function_last' has been called.");
}

function_first();
```