# How can I access A function variable in B function . this is in php

Tags: php

Here is my code.
I want to access $var1 in B function.

```
function a(){
    $var1="hello";  
}

function b(){
    echo $var1;
}

b();
```

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place? This seems like a major application design failure.

Comment: actually i am working in custom functions in wordpress. so i need it

Comment: @Dormilich there are many reasons you may need to do this. Everyone can read about it here though http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php google your question first at least

Comment: _IF_ you really need to do that, you'd have to have `a()` [return](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) your `$var1` and then call `a()` from within `b()`

Comment: use **global** keyword

Comment: Can you please put here example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a function inside of another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524877/how-do-i-call-a-function-inside-of-another-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by this way:

```
function a(){
    return "hello";  
}

function b(){
    $var1 = a();
    echo $var1;
    // or simply echo a();
}

b();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :-

```
$var1 = "";
function a(){
    global $var1;
    $var1 = "hello";  
}

function b(){
    global $var1;
    echo $var1;
}
a(); //first call a() to store 'hello' in global variable
echo b();
```

You can use the global variable `$var1` anywhere and in any function.

Comment: Using global variables is generally discouraged.  There are much better ways of achieving the required solution.

Comment: May be you are right. but the OP wants to use a variable which is initialized in other function. So, I thought of using `global` is better in this case