# Is there a way to add a function to my current button?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using JS and HTML. I have a button that displays the next section of html, but I wanted to add an additional function.

```js
// Display Thanks Message
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", addPerson function() {  
    q5.style.display = "none";
    end.style.display = "block";}
});
```

In this addPerson is the function I am trying to include. In this current code I keep getting syntax errors.

Comment: What is `addPerson` supposed to be? If it's the name of the function, JavaScript requires it to be between `function` and the `()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a function inside of another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524877/how-do-i-call-a-function-inside-of-another-function)

Answer (score 0):

Call `addPerson()` inside the function.

```js
// Display Thanks Message
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
      addPerson();
      q5.style.display = "none";
      end.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
});
```